# Minimization with Scipy returns a nan

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an optimization problem based o Hsieh Model, using scipy.minimize library in python. My problem consist in minimize obj function.

```
def obj(x1):
    global D
    x1 = taus2()
    x1 = x1.reshape((3, i, r))    

    sf()
    H_trf(x1)
    w_tilf(x1)
    p_irf(x1)
    Wf(x1)
    simul()

    D = np.sum((W/W_t - 1)**2 + (p_ir/p_t - 1)**2)
    return D
```

To do this, my algorithm must find the x1 array that minimizes the obj function.

```
x1 = np.array( [tau_w, tau_h, w] )
```

However, my functions, H_trf() and w_tilf() sometimes returns a NaN, consequently obj returns Nan. This is because these functions, depending on the values of x1, return negative values with fractional exponents.

```
calibration(2000)

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
*******************Hsieh Model********************
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Elapsed time: 64.72715544700623

tau_w is given by: 
 [[ 0.3343  0.3343  0.3343  0.3343]
 [-0.2921  0.3847 -0.0496  0.2864]]

tau_h is given by: 
 [[ 0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [-0.0712  0.8344 -0.3284  0.1354]]

w is given by: 
 [[0.6689 0.1587 0.4819 1.    ]
 [0.4976 0.3698 0.6231 1.    ]]

The minimun value to D is: nan

****************End of calibration****************
```

I use np.seterr, but doesn't work.

```
np.seterr(all='ignore')
```

Is there a way for Scipy to work around this problem? Or is there another library that can solve this? My complete code can be view in my [Github](https://github.com/mj-ribeiro/College-works.github.io/blob/master/Thesis/Hsieh_model.py). I apreciate any help.

Comment: What about modifying your functions so that they don't return NaN or using appropriate boundaries for the optimization so no NaN will be triggered?

Comment: According to theory taus has no limite and w must greater than zero. Só the reason to do this is theoretical.